# Buy Now button with a selection for the number of tickets requested

Tags: multipleselection

I want to place an html form on a page that has a drop-down selection for the number of tickets requested e.g. 1 - 8.

I am new to doing this type of PayPal input.  A link to an example would be appreciated.

Thank you for your assistance...

Todd Cary

Comment: Welcome to SO, you need to show us your attempt at this problem and we can help you after.

Answer (score 0):

A simple drop down selection can be done like this:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
</select>
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/theStudent/E5v66/

Comment: I am not sure how to integrate that into the PayPal form.  Does PayPal have an example?  Each ticket would be $25 and there is no shopping cart.

Comment: well you will need to do some javascript or jQuery, you need to show us some code sample you already have done. I don't know what you have with PayPal so I can't help you much there. But this is not very difficult to do with jQuery to calculate the amount $ as a total from the selected value.